# Atmosphere down? Meteorite dependent upon it?

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to install some packages using meteorite in my meteor project, but when I do "sudo mrt add " the command just hangs.

When I go to atmosphere, none of the smart package info is loading. So my question is, is it possible that the mrt add command is not working because atmosphere is experiencing problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is the case. `mrt` command consults atmosphere server on where it should take the package from. When their server is down, we can all take a coffee break.

If you just want to add a package and know its github repo (they're usually easy to find), you can add it manually by putting all its code in `/packages/packagename` folder within your app. This will allow you to work further without waiting for the atmosphere to stand up.

Answer (score 2):

it's actually the meteor server that is down, that's what they run it on, some of my apps up on meteor.com still work though but that one is down